# Equivalent of php's $var=$_POST["var"] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this JavaScript code somewhere and I want the "hours" to be variable input or selected from html form (much like php $_post) instead of manually changing the "hours" value (currently 2) by always editing the script.

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('#h_timer').countdowntimer({
 hours :2,
 size : "lg"
 });
 });
</script>
```

What I tried: (edit, thanks for the replies)

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
<select id="newHour" name="newHour">
<option id="duration" value="0" selected></option>
<option id="duration" value="2">2 Hours</option>
<option id="duration" value="4">4 Hours</option>
</select>
</form>

function sethour(){
     duration = $("#duration").val();
    }
```

Note: onChange, the timer should reset to the selected duration.

Comment: Have you tried to resolve this yourself yet? If so, great! Please edit your question to include what you have tried and the result. If not, please give it a shot and come back. A little hint though, I would take a look at JavaScript's [events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) (more specifically the `onchange` one).

Comment: You should not mix JQuery and native JS. `document.getElementById("newHour").value` is equivilent to `$("#newHour").val()`. But in this case you need the *option* value, not the select value.

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've written? Should selecting a `newHour` reinitialize the existing countdown timer? Or should it reload the page like a form submission?